# Tomcat 7 The requested resource is not available

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have written a Java servlet and run it through local Tomcat 7, but when I copied the war file that I have written to another computer and copied it to the webapps folder in the tomcat directory, but I keep getting the "requested resource is not available" message, while in my computer everything works fine, what could be the problem?

Comment: can you see your application in the tomcat manager?

Comment: I don't know, I don't have the user name and the password to access the tomcat manager. But I deployed the war file in the webapps folder of the tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the console are you getting any error? is server started properly? Have you set JAVA_HOME in environmental variable?
To check if the server is started properly or not type following url in the browser:

http://localhost:8080/

of the computer where you have deployed the war. replace 8080 with appropriate port number if you are not starting the server at port 8080. If you are able to see tomcat page then the server is started properly.

if you are getting no error on console then everything seems correct and you are typing an incorrect url in the browser.
I think you must be getting exception on the console as you said war was working on the previous system . Make sure you set JAVA_HOME to appropriate jdk or jre version(ex 1.6) which is used to develop the war.

Comment: OK, i'm now getting that error: The requested resource (Servlet Sample is not available) is not available. And yes, I can see the tomcat main page.

Comment: maybe the mistake is in the web.xml file? I don't know, can you help me?

Comment: please paste the full console output. As you are getting error so I am assuming the JAVA_HOME is set.still you can check it in MyComputer->Properties->Advanced->EnvironmentalVariables. If you are in linux system or unix then google for setting environmental variables.If you are on windows then you can google for the same if you are not able to set. Paste console output that will be helpfull,also web.xml.

Comment: I'm using windows server 2008, where can I check this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have not mapped the URL correctly . Tomcat does not know what to hit with the current URL